# What is the difference between Ordinary reinforced concrete shear walls and special reinforced concrete shear walls?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

In ASCE 7-10 Table 12.2-1 two types of shear walls can be used ordinary reinforced concrete shear walls and special reinforced concrete shear walls what is it the difference between these walls ? (Reinforcement, Shape, Usage) and when do i use each type ?

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the obvious (different R value, Cd, Omega), you get a system that allows for higher ductility and thus less shear transfer requirement. Reinforcement requirements for the intermediate wall is noted in TMS to adhere to section 1.17.3.2.3.1 and also not exceed vertical reinforcement spacing of 48" o.c. (section 1.17.3.2.5).